# object and its inheritance

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can't understand the difference between object instance and object inheritance instance:

1.`__dict__`, `__module__`, `__weakref__` - where this properties from?

```
>>> dir(object)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
>>> dir(type('tt',(object,),{}))
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
```

2.I can't set propetry to object instance.

```
>>> b= object()
>>> b.f = 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'f'
>>> b = type('tt',(object,),{})()
>>> b.f = 4
```

Does this difference come from builtin type builder? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

`__dict__` is the dictionary each python object has that stores it's variables eg. `foo.x` will lookup `foo.__dict__['x']` (some classes use [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots) instead to save space)

`__module__` refers to the module of the class.

```
>>> object.__module__
'__builtin__' # object is part of the builtin module
```

`__weakref__` is a reference to the object, this is used by the `weakref` module to keep a reference to the object without affecting the reference count garbage collection system. See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html) for it's uses.

2.

You can't set properties on an `object()` instance because it doesn't have a `__dict__`,

```
>>> dir(object)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

it is only used as a base class for every other class and does not need one.

Using `type` as you did actually creates a subclass of `object`, also you have given it a `{}` for it's attributes so of course `b.f = 4` will work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, some types are immutable. `int` and `tuple` are immutable, for example, and so is a plain `object` instance. The same limitation does not apply to subclasses; you can subclass `int` and give it mutable attributes, the same applies to `object`.

The `__dict__` attribute is added to custom classes by the class builder (`type()`); it is the namespace mapping for the class; attribute lookups on a class are translated to key lookups in that structure. `object` on the other hand is a Python C type, and attributes and methods in C are handled differently. Python C types are expected to implement the [C Type interface](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html) instead. For some types `.__dict__` can be dereferenced but you'll find it is a read-only proxy object instead as C types cannot be altered dynamically the way custom types can.

The `__module__` attribute is *available* on `object` and `int`:

```
>>> object.__module__
'builtins'
>>> int.__module__
'builtins'
```

but because these are built-in types the attribute makes little sense really and is not listed in `dir()`.

The `__weakref__` attribute is an implementation detail of the [`weakref` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html). Together with the `__dict__` attribute the `type()` constructor sets this attribute on custom classes, if no [`__slots__` attribute](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots) has been set on the class. Like the `__dict__` attribute you found another difference between custom classes and C-type objects. For Python C types, different entries in the [C type object structure](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html) fill the same role.